# The second query is not executing in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm newbie in `PHP` and `WordPress`. This approach was working fine for me in `ASP.NET` but here both queries are not working. When I comment the first one, the second one(Insertion) is working fine.

```
$dbhostname="111.1.11.111"; 
$dbusername="db_userName";
$dbpassword="mypassword";

$con=mysqli_connect($dbhostname,$dbusername,$dbpassword,"db_name");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Check wether the email exists or not ?

```
$sql="CALL Select_ConfirmEmailExistance('abc@abc.com')";

  $containsResult=0;
 if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
 // Get field information for all fields
 while ($fieldinfo=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
    if (isset($fieldinfo)) {
        $containsResult=1;// Email Exists 
    }
}
mysqli_free_result($result);

if ($containsResult==0) { // In case email does not exists enter it.

    $sql="CALL insert_Userinfo('abc','def','abc@abc.com','mnop')";
    if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        $data;
        while ($fieldinfo=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $data[]=$fieldinfo;
        }
    }
  }
  print_r($data);
  }

mysqli_close($con);
```

**First Store Procdure**

```
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 as emailstatus FROM userinfo WHERE email= p_email;
END
```

**Second Stored Procedure**

```
INSERT INTO `userinfo` (
    `first_name`,
    `last_name`,
    `email`,
    `password`
)
VALUES
    (
        `FName`,
        `LName`,
        `Email`,
        `Pass`
    );

SELECT
    user_id
FROM
    userinfo
ORDER BY
    user_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: @pr1nc3 the database which i'm calling is not the wordpress database. that is other.

Comment: provide your store procedure code here

Comment: @BhumiShah the store procedure's are working fine.any how i'm sharing the store procedures. when i'm using one query in at a time  the both queries are working fine,it creates problem when i'm calling both at a time.

Comment: Why not create a function or class/method to return your queries? They are self-contained and are less likely to conflict when you are using the same variables in each call.

Comment: @Rasclatt i'm trying to call both queries in other methods. i'm also facing to page redirect with word press? what should i do for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I was talking about when I said create a query class to fetch data. This is just a simple one, but it works pretty effectively and you can build it out to be pretty powerful.

```
class   DBEngine
    {
        public  $con;
        public  function __construct($host="111.1.11.111",$db = "dbname",$user="db_userName",$pass="mypassword")
            {
                try {
                        $this->con  =   new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
                    }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                      return 0;
                    }
            }

        // Simple fetch and return method
        public  function Fetch($_sql)
            {
                $query  =   $this->con->prepare($_sql);
                $query->execute();

                if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
                        while($rows = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                $array[]    =   $rows;
                            }
                    }

                return (isset($array) && $array !== 0 && !empty($array))? $array: 0;
            }

        // Simple write to db method
        public  function Write($_sql)
            {
                $query  =   $this->con->prepare($_sql);
                $query->execute();
            }
    }

// Create an instance of the engine
$query          =   new DBEngine();
// Query 1 will return an array or false (0)
$call1          =   $query->Fetch("CALL Select_ConfirmEmailExistance('abc@abc.com')");
// Assign your true/false
$containsResult =   ($call1 !== 0)? 1:0;
// Run second query and return array or false (0)
if($containsResult == 0)
    $data   =   $query->Fetch("CALL insert_Userinfo('abc','def','abc@abc.com','mnop')");
// Display returned result
print_r($data);
```

Comment: your code is pretty elaborate. really appreciate that. thank you very much for such help.

Comment: No problem. Actually, it only looks elaborate at first glance. If you put the `DBEngine` class in your config file or where ever you are housing your database connection, you can run them simultaneously if you want. Just test it out and I guarantee you will like it! Try a simple `select * from whatevertable` sql and see how it runs.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple. Your code is fine but you only have to create two separete functions and simply call those functions instead of the code directly.